# Create a generic serializer with a dynamic model in Meta

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

when i create a Serializer in django-rest0-framework, based on a ModelSerializer, i will have to pass the model in the Meta class:

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

I want to create a general serializer which, based on the URL, includes the model dynamically.

My setup thusfar includes the urls.py and the viewset:

urls.py:

```
 url(r'^api/v1/general/(?P<model>\w+)', kernel_api_views.GeneralViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'}))
```

and views.py:

```
class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def get_queryset(self):
            # Dynamically get the model class from myapp.models
            queryset = getattr(myapp.models, model).objects.all()
            return queryset

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         return getattr(myapp.serializers, self.kwargs['model']+'Serializer')
```

Which in case of: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/general/Client gets Client.objects.all() as queryset and the ClientSerializer class as serializer

**Question:** How can i make it so that i can call 'GeneralSerializer' and dynamically assign the model in it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do that by following:

**serializers.py**

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = None
```

**views.py**

```
class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def get_queryset(self):
         model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return model.objects.all()           

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return GeneralSerializer
```

In `serializers.py`, we define a `GeneralSerializer` having `model` in `Meta` as `None`. We'll override the `model` value at the time of calling `get_serializer_class()`.

Then in our `views.py` file, we define a `GeneralViewSet` with `get_queryset()` and  `get_serializer_class()` overridden.

In `get_queryset()`, we obtain the value of the `model` from `kwargs` and return that queryset.

In  `get_serializer_class()`, we set the value of `model` for `GeneralSerializer` to the value obtained from `kwargs` and then return the `GeneralSerializer`.

Comment: Just for anybody that views this in the future, this solution isn't thread-safe, as you're changing that `GeneralSerializer.Meta.model` attribute and that stays between executions. 
If you're running your instance with multiple threads, you could run into some hard to debug issues.

Answer (score 11):

So far I know you cannot create a generic serializer if you use model serializer, but you can get the same solution using a base class and deriving all your models from that base class. Implement a method to return the serializer and then use that method to generate a dynamic serializer. I am using this technique for the last 2 years and working pretty fine for me -

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         abstract = True # define abstract so that it does not cause any problem with model hierarchy in database

    @classmethod
    def get_serializer(cls):
         class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
               class Meta:
                    model = cls # this is the main trick here, this is how I tell the serializer about the model class

         return BaseSerializer #return the class object so we can use this serializer
```

Now derive your models from it -

```
class Derived1(BaseModel):
    pass

class Derived2(BaseModel):
    pass
```

if you want to override the serializer then just do it in the one that you need. for example -

```
class DerivedOverride(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def get_serializer(cls):
         super_serializer = BaseModel.get_serializer() # this important to not to break the serializing hierarchy
         class BaseSerializer(super_serializer):
               class Meta:
                    model = cls # this is the main trick here, this is how I tell the serializer about the model class

         return BaseSerializer
```

Thats it, now each class has its own dynamic serializer but we just defined it in one place.

Now use the serializer in view set -

```
class Derive1ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Derived1.get_serializer()

class Derive2ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Derived2.get_serializer()
```

and go on from there.

Answer (score 4):

To build on Rahul's answer, this is what worked for me:

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/(?P<app_label>\w+)/(?P<model_name>\w+)', GeneralViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = None
```

views.py

```
from django.apps import apps        
class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @property
    def model(self):
        return apps.get_model(app_label=str(self.kwargs['app_label']), model_name=str(self.kwargs['model_name']))

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = self.model
        return model.objects.all()           

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = self.model
        return GeneralSerializer
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Rahul and @btal, we can use decorator pattern on `ModelSerializer` in case if we want to use `APIView`.

```py
def getGenericSerializer(model_arg):
    class GenericSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = model_arg
            fields = '__all__'

    return GenericSerializer
```

And use it like this in the APIView:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        #...
        GenericSzl = getGenericSerializer(model)
        serializer = GenericSzl(objs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope this helps to those people who don't want to use `ModelViewSet`.

Answer (score 2):

For Django 3.0+

```
from yourapp import models

class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def get_queryset(self):
         model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return getattr(models, model).objects.all()         

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         GeneralSerializer.Meta.model =  getattr(models, model)
         return GeneralSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Create general serializer without `model` in `Meta`:

```
class GeneralModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

Add `model` to serializer in ``:

```
class GenericViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = GeneralModelSerializer
        serializer_class.Meta.model = YourModel
        return serializer_class
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Create general serializer with or without model, send model name in url

plugin: django-geojson==2.12.0
django: 2.0.6
python: 3.6.7

api.py

```
from djgeojson.serializers import Serializer as GeoJSONSerializer
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection


def to_geojson(request):
        model = request.GET['model']
        print(model)
        lista = []
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (model))
            # to dict
            lista = dictfetchall(cursor)
            # Serialize
            geo_lista = GeoJSONSerializer().serialize(lista)
        return HttpResponse(geo_lista)


    def dictfetchall(cursor):
        "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
        columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
        return [
            dict(zip(columns, row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/geo/', to_geojson, name='to_geojson')
```

my urls to call API:
with model in models.py

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/api/geo/?model=data_pointcloud
```

without model in models.py

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/api/geo/?model="schema".table_name
```