# How to create a CRUD REST API for all Django models with DRF?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

How would one go about taking all models from all applications in django and then expose all of them under a systematic CRUD endpoint such as `api/models/****` without writing DRF Views for each model individually? In other words, how does one create a generic CRUD API for all models of a django server to quickly modify data in the database via REST?

So if we have this application file structure

```
application/
  /auth
    /models
      /token.py
      /other_model.py
  /shop
 /profile
 /...
```

It would result in the following CRUD endpoints

```
domain.com/api/models/auth/token
domain.com/api/models/auth/other_model
domain.com/api/models/shop/card
...
```

Further, these generic endpoints could allow basic filtering (by id, define return fields with a `?fields=...` parameter etc.

I know about [Eve](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/) but we are committed to django/DRF and we want to cut away a lot of redundant `model-serializer-view` verticals that offer little value for lots of code.

Comment: Found this on google: https://github.com/Brobin/drf-generators, I am not sure if this library is maintained regularly or not, but its Django version is bit old. If you no problem with that, then I think you can look into this.

Comment: that looks like it generates code. I was aiming for a runtime generation of the classes based on a list of all models classes. Maybe something using the `type(...)` abilities of  Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831731/create-a-generic-serializer-with-a-dynamic-model-in-meta