# django ModelSerializer pass variable to meta sub-class

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I, trying to find the cleanest implementation to access context from the meta sub-class in a django serializer

### views.py:

```
import someapp.models as models
import someapp.serializers as serializer

def some_view(request, batch_id):
    exp_type = models.UploadModel.objects.filter(batch_id=batch_id).values()[0]['experiment_type']
    model_idx = get_obj_idx_from_exp(model_names, exp_type)
    use_model = model_objs[model_idx]
    model_data = use_model.objects.filter(batch_id=batch_id)
    list_data = serializer.GeneralSerializer(model_data, many=True, context={'model': use_model}).data
    ...
```

### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from someapp import models

class GeneralSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # can access self.context['model'] here
    class Meta:
    # can NOT access self.context['model'] here
    model = self.context['model']
    fields, _ = zip(*self.context['model'].display_fields())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**serializers.py**

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = None
```

**views.py**

```
class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def get_queryset(self):
         model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return model.objects.all()           

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return GeneralSerializer
```

See more here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831731/create-a-generic-serializer-with-a-dynamic-model-in-meta)