# Create generic viewset and serializer for models in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-viewsets

I am making a lot of views and serializers for my models that takes all fields. They all look like this:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would like to make a generic Viewset and Serializer for that can simply take inn my model. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831731/create-a-generic-serializer-with-a-dynamic-model-in-meta) to be helpful, but I would rather not have the model in the url. If possible, I would send the model with the router.register:

```
router.register('my_url', MyView(MyModel), basename='my-basename')
```

but this gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: This method is available only on the class, not on instances.
```

Any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: You must use the viewset class, ie `MyModelViewSet` with routers, not an instance of the viewset, ie `MyModelViewSet(...)`

Comment: You can adjust/arrange the router class the way you want by creating a custom router by inheriting the existing one

Comment: @JPG I understand I have to use the class, but how do I then send inn the model I need for that url?

Comment: Thats what I have already mentioned *in other words*, which is, "*it is not possible with built-in setup*"

Comment: @JPG I see, I will look into custom router then

Answer (score 0):

I came across when looking for the same problem. Note that in your `GeneralViewSet` you have to get the model from `self.model`. So the correct code for looping all models:

```
classes={}
for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
    name = model.__name__
    classes[name]=type(name, (views.GeneralViewSet,), {})
    classes[name].model=model
    router.register(name ,classes[name], basename=name)
```